# Appcelerator map annotation click behaviour

Tags: android, maps, titanium, appcelerator

Does any one knows how to prevent changing region on map when annotation is clicked.

I'm creating annotation simply like that:

```
var mountainView = Alloy.Globals.Map.createAnnotation({
  latitude: drivers[i]['last_position']['lat'],
  longitude: drivers[i]['last_position']['lng'],
  title: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.dpi,
  subtitle: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.density,
  image: img,
});
```

And when i click it it changing region of whole map with this annotation at the center.

Can i prevent it? (just to open bubble)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "showInfoWindow" so it won't center the view but it won't open the bubble. You still get the click event so you can open other views